# Share data between components with Subject

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to share data between two components in Angular 6 with Subject.
Somehow it does not work and I can not find out why. I need to pass data from compare.component to profile.component with click. When I click, data is not passed. But somehow when I go back and then click again, it works. 
What do I do wrong?

data.service

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

export class DataService {
  data = new Subject();
}
```

profile.component

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  sendData(x) {
    this.dataService.data.next(x);
    this.router.navigate(['compare']);
  }
}
```

compare.component

```
export class CompareComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.data.subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where are you calling sendData()?

Comment: Did you do it like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hrkjwp?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Im guessing ProfileComponent and CompareComponent do not have the same service instance. Someone elseo mentioned using BehaviorSubject. This would be necessary if you would have more than one subscriber to this Subject, but in your code sample this is not the case. If you do have multiple subscriber, it indeed should be a BehaviorSubject.

Answer (score 3):

In service:

```
export class DataService {
  private data = new Subject<any>();
  public data$ = this.data.asObservable();

  emitdata(x: any){
    this.data.next(x);
  }
}
```

In profile component:

```
sendData(x){
this.dataservice.emitdata(x);
}
```

In compare component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.data$.subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Great!, works to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use BehaviorSubject It will subscribe the latestvalue

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

export class DataService {
//You can set initial value as well if you want new BehaviorSubject('value');
  data = new BehaviorSubject();
}
```