# Angular transfer data between two unrelated components

Tags: angular, angular-components, subscribe

I have two elements in my angular project that are completely independent. The first one shows a list of license plates and two buttons for each plate: "View current position" and "View positions for the last 24h". Those two buttons redirect to the same component which shows in a map some points depending of a variable "method". I want to set the "method" in a certain value when the button is clicked, but I have no idea how to do this.

I have tried about the Subject/Subscribe thing but did not work for me. It is possible that I did not apply it properly, as I am not very confident about how it works. In the examples I have found, the subject was emmited by some @Injectable, but I am working with two @Component.

Thank you all.

Edit: I will try to explain what I have tried.

I have the service

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { MatriculasListadoComponent } from "../components/matriculas-listado/matriculas-listado.component";
import { Metodos } from "../models/metodos";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConexionDataService {
    metodoBoton: Subject<Metodos>
  
    constructor() {
      this.metodoBoton = new Subject<Metodos>();
    }
    
    }
```

Then I have a method in my component from where I want to send the data which is called clicking the buttons:

```
constructor(private matriculaService: MatriculaService, private conexionDataService: ConexionDataService) {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Matricula>([]);
  }

...

enviarMetodo(metodo:Metodos) {
    this.conexionDataService.metodoBoton.next(metodo);
  }
```

And I have this NgOnInit in the component where I want to recieve the data

```
providers: [ListaPosicionesService, DatePipe, ConexionDataService]

...

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.conexionDataService.metodoBoton.subscribe(log=> {
      this.metodo=log
      console.log(log)
    })
```

I am getting log as "undefined". Probably I am not doing it properly as I do not understand at all how those services work...

Comment: Please add some more details, provide code snippet it would help a lot in understanding why it is not working.

Comment: You need to provide your code. Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51660156/share-data-between-components-with-subject

Comment: @DevangPatel  I have added the code, I hope you can help me

Comment: @Anuj.T code added

Comment: @Videgain just change subject in your service to behaviorSubject.
in my answer i have share the demo how to use behavior subject.

Answer (score 2):

When passing data between components that lack a direct connection, such as siblings, grandchildren, etc, you should use a shared service. When you have data that should aways been in sync, I find the RxJS BehaviorSubject very useful in this situation.

You can also use a regular RxJS Subject for sharing data via the service, but here’s why I prefer a BehaviorSubject.

1. It will always return the current value on subscription - there is no need to call onnext
2. It has a getValue() function to extract the last value as raw data.
3. It ensures that the component always receives the most recent data.

Details explanation by [Jeff Delaney](https://fireship.io/contributors/jeff-delaney/) is [here](https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/)

***Here is the working demo*** ***-->***
[BehaviorSubject | Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/redirect-user-after-change-6r437g?file=src/app/about/about.component.html)

**shared service**

```
private metodoSource = new BehaviorSubject({ id: '1', name: 'default' });
metodoCurrent = this.metodoSource.asObservable();
```

**Parent-Component**

```
constructor(private data: DataService)

changeMetodo() {
//this is sample data you can use your metodo model
 let data = {
   id: '2',
   name: 'xyz',
   changeFrom: 'homeComponent',
 };
 this.data.changeMetodo(data);
}
```

**sibling-Component**

```
constructor(private data: DataService)
ngOnInit() {
this.metodoSubscription = this.data.metodoCurrent.subscribe((metodo) => {
  this.metodo = metodo;
});
```

}

Whenever the parent emits using the next method, you can receive the data
in other component and act on it.

In the demo which i have created, it will redirect as well and updated data will be available in the other component we redirected to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/guide/store). This will allow you to communicate between components easily without creating the relation "parent-child" between them.

Just dispatch an action from your current component and create an effect to catch and trigger the other component

Answer (score 0):

If its a complicated app then NGRX to maintain state is a good idea. However, its a lot of boilerplate code for a simple app where BehaviourSubjects maybe what you are after.

BehaviourSubjects are observables that require initialisation. They tend to sit on an existing service you may have defined (DI injected via your component constructor).

[BehaviorSubject vs Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494058/behaviorsubject-vs-observable)

The flow is like this...

Define your BehaviourSubject on a service. Mine is a service called CommonSvc. Here is a good article about services. https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

```
public loadingSub: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
```

Create a public method to expose the subject and set the next value

```
  public setLoading(loading: boolean,): void {
      this.loadingSub.next(loading);
  }
```

On your component, inject your service into the constructor.

```
private commonSvc: CommonService
```

You can now access the BehaviourSubject directly. Something like this.

```
  this.commonSvc.loadingSub
  .subscribe((loading) => {
    this.loading = loading;
  });
```

...and it you need to update the BehaviourSubject, call the public method.

```
this.commonSvc.setLoading(true);
```

Now, the beauty of this method is that everywhere you subscribe to the BehaviourSubject, the same value will be presented. You can inject the service anywhere in your components so it makes it pretty flexible too.

The downside is that when you have lots of them (Subjects & BehaviourSubjects) they can get tricky to manage. That's where NGRX comes in.

PS. If you are subscribing to subscriptions, don't forget to unsubscribe when you are done.